# How to move requestId and caller to the HTTP headers?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We're trying to encrypt our payload and move anything that shouldn't be encrypted.

So far, these are the attributes that we identified not to be encrypted.

-- event.requestContext.requestId

-- event.requestContext.requestId.identity.caller

So, how can I move these items to the HTTP header?

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish.  You say you want to "encrypt the payload" but why?  For what purpose?  Before you do something else with the payload, presumably, but what?  Where is the payload going, next?  Who's encrypting it, and at what point? Can you be more specific and provide some clarifying details, please?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Basically, we want to encrypt our payload since there are sensitive data in it. So, before we send out the request to another endpoint, we want to encrypt the payload first. But, before that, we want to get those attributes mentioned first and move them to the HTTP header.

Comment: So, first, what I want to know is how to get these attributes

Comment: Are you referring to the request that your Lambda receives or the response that your Lambda sends?

Comment: @dashmug The request I'm referring to is the request from an API Gateway that will be sent to another API Gateway

Comment: @Steven There are multiple ways of doing that. It depends on your integration type and runtime. Can you provide more details about your API Gateway Integration with Lambda?

Comment: @dashmug We're currently using Lambda function as the integration type and "Use Lambda Proxy integration" is checked. If it's necessary to change this configuration, that would be okay as long as the goal will be achieved.

Comment: @Steven Please give more details. How are you making one API Gateway call another API Gateway? I think you mean one Lambda calling another API Gateway (through an HTTP call) unless the first API Gateway is just a proxy for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i understand correctly and this is a nodejs question you can use:

```
request.setHeader(KEY,VALUE);
```

This way you can put the request.callerId in the value and create new Key for this header entry, like CALLER_ID. 
Usually the key syntax is in capital letters.

Update:

Ok, so if you use aws-lambda you need to create custom request with curl that contain wrapper for the lambda payload, follow this manual:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/